# Convert C callback API to Stream

Tags: rust

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=edafa63d75784eff7159b03e79972b46)

I've got access to the pulseaudio via an async C api.

```rust
pub fn get_sink_info_by_index<F>(
    &self,
    index: u32,
    callback: F
) -> Operation<dyn FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInfo>)> where
    F: FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInfo>) + 'static,
```

Source: https://docs.rs/libpulse-binding/2.16.1/libpulse_binding/context/introspect/struct.Introspector.html#method.get_sink_info_by_index

I've implemented a helper function (which compiles just fine) which generates me a callback to pass to the C function and the output stream.

```rust
pub fn callbackStream<T:Sized + Clone>() -> (Box<dyn FnMut(ListResult<&'static T>)>, Box<dyn Stream<Item=T>>) {
    let (sender, recv) = channel(1024); // TODO channel size?
    let cb  = {|c: ListResult<&'static T>| match c {
        Item(it) => match sender.try_send(it.clone()) {
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(err) => () // TODO
        },
        End => (),
        Error => () // TODO
    }};
    (Box::new(cb), Box::new(recv))
}
```

However, when trying to use it, I can't get the lifetimes to work:

```
    fn stream_sink_info_by_index(
        &self,
        index: u32
    ) -> Box<dyn Stream<Item=SinkInfo>> {
        let (callback, stream): (Box<dyn FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInfo>) + 'static>, Box<dyn Stream<Item=SinkInfo>>) = callbackStream();
        self.get_sink_info_by_index(index, callback);
        stream
    }
```

gives me

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/futuristicPulse.rs:31:117
   |
31 |         let (callback, stream): (Box<dyn FnMut(ListResult<&SinkInfo>) + 'static>, Box<dyn Stream<Item=SinkInfo>>) = callbackStream();
   |                                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter
   |                                 |
   |                                 expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected tuple `(std::boxed::Box<(dyn for<'r, 's> std::ops::FnMut(pulse::callbacks::ListResult<&'r pulse::context::introspect::SinkInfo<'s>>) + 'static)>, std::boxed::Box<dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = pulse::context::introspect::SinkInfo<'_>>>)`
              found tuple `(std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(pulse::callbacks::ListResult<&'static _>) + 'static)>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = _> + 'static)>)`

error: aborting due to previous error; 10 warnings emitted
```

If I adjust the type annotation on `(callback, stream)` to what the typechecker finds me, I the error is forwarded to the call to `get_sink_info_by_index`:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r, 's> <std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::FnMut(pulse::callbacks::ListResult<&'static pulse::context::introspect::SinkInfo<'_>>)> as std::ops::FnOnce<(pulse::callbacks::ListResult<&'r pulse::context::introspect::SinkInfo<'s>>,)>>::Output == ()`
  --> src/futuristicPulse.rs:32:14
   |
32 |         self.get_sink_info_by_index(index, callback);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime

error: aborting due to previous error; 10 warnings emitted
```

Comment: Have you tried combining `callbackStream` and `stream_sink_info_by_index` into one function? I think that might help simplify things a bit.

Comment: I could certainly try, but I've got about 8 other functions like `get_sink_info_by_index`, so a bit of abstraction would be nice.

Comment: Fair enough. Why don't you try replacing the type in `let (callback, stream): xyz` with the type after "found tuple ..." from the error message?

Comment: Did, added it to the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rough answer - the issue did lie with `it.clone()`. It didn't properly transfer ownership, because it was a `SinkInfo<'r>` instead of just a `SinkInfo`. I wrote a `SinkInfo<'r> -> SinkInfo<'static>` and now everything works.